# Spring Data Mongodb optional parameter with between dates

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create json query with three optional field in spring data mongodb.

1. status
2. startdate and enddate for between. Below is the query i have created but this is failing. its failing with json parsing error, I am not sure what is wrong

   @Query("{$and: [{$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { status : ?0 } ]}, {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' , $where: '?2 == null' } , { createdDate : {$gt : ?1, $lt : ?2}} ]}]}")

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong and help me to create the query with these optional parameters ?